# How to reproduce experiments in a non-adhoc manner

Tags: distributed, distributed-computing, experimental-design

For a master thesis in the field of distributed computing (think of hadoop and two-level schedulers like Mesos) I'm setting up various experiments on a university cluster.

However I'm already piling up bash scripts which function as a driver for the experiment. I miss composability and reuse between subparts of experiments.

Are there any frameworks out there which allows one to reuse various parts without ending up with tightly coupled components.

I've found a possible candidate called [Nepi](http://nepi.inria.fr/), but was wondering how other people bring some well defined form in their distributed experiments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a a good survey on [experiment description languages](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01087519/file/main.pdf).